# SQL Server : How to do a NEXT VALUE FOR in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a sequence whose name is saved in a table called `tableName`.
I want to create the table test with the sequence name in `tableName`.

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
     T_ID INT default (NEXT VALUE FOR (Select x from tableName)
)
```

Comment: You're looking for the `IDENTITY()` property.

Comment: Are you trying to mimic an Oracle Sequence in SQL Server? If so check out SQL Server Identity column feature `T_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`.

Comment: @JeffMergler, Microsoft implemented `SEQUENCE` objects in SQL Server 2012. Took 'em a while, but they got there.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Specifically, I think that the constraint has to be deterministic (note - I'm not saying that the values the constraint produces need to be deterministic) and by trying to have the constraint depend on the data in a table, it's not.

Comment: So what is a solution to this problem? If I want to do something like that

Comment: Please explain what problem you are trying to solve by dynamic sequence names.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use dynamic SQL, if you wish to use a sequence name stored in a table as a part of a select.
If you need to get numbers from sequence in a stored procedure, you can use procedure `sp_sequence_get_range`, it accepts sequence name as a parameter.

There is an example how to create sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.tableSequence  
    AS int  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

Example for select:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.tableSequence FROM dbo.tableName
```

Example for default value of primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tableName  
(  
    EventID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
        DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.tableSequence),  
    EventTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),  
    EventCode nvarchar(5) NOT NULL,  
    Description nvarchar(300) NULL  
) ;  
GO
```

You can learn more about TSQL sequnces at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What if the name of the sequence is save in another table therefore to know the name of the sequence we need to do a select statement. Then how it should be implemented

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL in such case.